# HTTP Post Token Autorization, No trabaja

Tags: flutter, dart

Se requiere hacer una consulta de tipo post, para poder enviar la peticion se necesita enviar su token, en la siguiente imagen se usa Postaman, para testear la API, y funciona correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cuerpo(body) va asi:

```
{ "idTipoPago": 1,"idNegocio": 2,"idDireccion": 21,"latitud": "", "longitud": "", 
 "direccion": "", "referencia": "","servicio": 36.48400,"distancia": "3.9 
 km","distancia_value": 3914,"duration": "9 mins","duration_value": 512,"comprobante": 
 "","codigoPromocion": "", "idTipoOrden": 1,"fechaProgramada":"02/09/2020", "orden": 
[{"idArticulo": 8,"cantidad": 3,"instrucciones": "con Salsa habanera, tomate y 
limon","detalles": []}]}
```

Sin embargo, si esto se codifica en Dart, me regresa un error **500**,
el codigo desarrollado es este:

```
postCanastilla() async {
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": 
  token,'Accept': 'application/json'};
  String json =
    '{ "idTipoPago": 1,"idNegocio": 2,"idDireccion": 21,"latitud": "", "longitud": "", 
    "direccion": "", "referencia": "","servicio": 36.48400,"distancia": 
    "3.9km","distancia_value": 3914,"duration": "9 mins","duration_value": 
    512,"comprobante": "","codigoPromocion": "", "idTipoOrden": 
    1,"fechaProgramada":"02/09/2020", "orden": [{"idArticulo": 8,"cantidad": 
    3,"instrucciones": "con Salsa habanera, tomate y limon","detalles": []}]}';
 try {
    Response response =
    await post('https://pideexpress.com.mx/api/business/canasta', headers: headers, 
    body:json);
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    String body = response.body;

 if (statusCode == 200) {
    String responseJson = response.body.toString();
    print(responseJson);
    //postToken(context,responseJson );

 }else{
    print('entro al else');
 }
 } on Exception catch (exception) {
    print(exception);
    return false;
 }catch (error) {
    print(error);
    return false;
 }
}
```

**Gracias <3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu header debes enviar tu token de tipo bearer.

```
"Authorization": "bearer $token"
```

Tu header debería quedar así:

```
 Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "bearer $token", 'Accept': 'application/json'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que puedo detectar en postman y tu código es que desde postman le indicas que tu token es `Bearer Token` y en tus headers solo lo mandas como Authorization, lo que deberias de enviar en tu header es tu token de la siguiente manera.

`"authorization": "bearer $token"`